# My aspx c# in page_load request is always GET, how do I make it post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, pageload

I need call from RestTemplate Spring and in my page_load of aspx is always GET and send POST method from my client.

```cs
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")//This code is always GET and never is POST, i'm using RestTemplate library from android Spring postForObject method
            {
                MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
                Request.InputStream.CopyTo(memstream);
                memstream.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memstream))
                {
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

how to make to accept POST? In GET case my InputStream is empty.

**UPDATE**

My call from java android using RestTemplate  postForObject

```cs
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();         
            String lsObjeto = restTemplate.postForObject("http://xxxx/Service/Login", "{user:666,pwd:123}", String.class);  
            Log.v("URL", "Response: " + lsObjeto);
```

Comment: The likely answer is - it is a GET. What makes you think it is a POST? Please show us how you are making that POST request? If you POST to the endpoint using `Postman`, what happens?

Comment: mjwills i'm call from java android using resttemplate method postForObject. My code is updated

Comment: If you POST to the endpoint using `Postman`, what happens?

Comment: In postmant run POST, and test in javaservlt and also works with post method. When I checked by wireshark, it sends a first frame in post and having no answer forwards in POST it forwards in GET. Also configre IIS for acept POST from android?